# Load Balancer ID in Response Header

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, tomcat

Is it good practice to put a load balancer identifier in a response header? I'm using a Tomcat/Apache HTTP system and there doesn't seem to be a good way to verify which machine I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's a fairly common practice. I've also seen companies inject the backend ID into a commented-out html string.